# Проблемы с кодом (ANSI Common Lisp)

Tags: lisp

[image: Исходный код]

[image: Результат]

---

Выше скриншот из книги "ANSI Common Lisp".

Пару вопросов:

1. Почему корректно не работает данный код? Использую Common Lisp (SBCL). По задумке автора программа сначала выводит текст (Please enter a number), а затем ожидает ввод с клавиатуры. В моем же случае, программа сначала просит ввести данные с клавиатуры, в случае если я ввел не число, просит еще раз (до тех пор, пока не введу число), и только потом выводит текст с результатом ввода. Скриншот:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

2. Зачем используются лишние скобки: `(let ((val (read)))`? При попытке написать так: `(let (val (read))` - получил бесконечный цикл из "Please enter a number".

Answer (score 0):

1) возможно ошибка при наборе?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

2) в let можно много чего написать 
[написать](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/s_let_l.htm)

Answer (score 0):

Относительно 2.: `let` принимает список связываний переменных в формате `(переменная значение)` или `переменная`. Во втором случае переменной будет присвоено значение `nil`. В твоем примере `(let (val (read))` ты получишь следующие связывания:

- `val` - `nil`
- `read` - `nil`

Следовательно, условие `(numberp val)` никогда не будет выполнено.